# Error with GeoDjango serializer and ForeignKey field

Tags: django, python-2.7, serialization, geojson

I have a problem with **Django 1.5.4**. I put the question in StackOverflow instead of https://gis.stackexchange.com/ because I'm almost 100% sure is not a GIS related problem.

Here is my set up:

My *models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

# This models a region of interest, using a polygon
class ROI(gismodels.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='ROI')
    area = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    geom = gismodels.PolygonField(srid=4326)
    when = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    objects = gismodels.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.label)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['when']


class Indicator(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    color = models.TextField()
    measurement_units = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    algorithm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    data_origin = models.TextField()


class Series(models.Model):
    roi = models.ForeignKey(ROI)
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator)
```

As you can see, **Series model contains a reference to ROI model**

My *settings.py*

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'geojson': 'djgeojson.serializers'
}
```

I'm using [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson) to **serialize my ROI objects into GeoJSON**. I want to use this serializer to send a GeoJSON to my clients. So, my views.py looks like this

My *views.py*

```
@login_required
def get_rois(request):
    rois_query = ROI.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    polygons = json.loads(serializers.serialize('geojson', rois_query))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(polygons), mimetype='application/json')
```

The problem: **I'm getting this error in serialize call**

```
AttributeError: 'ROI' object has no attribute 'roi'
```

The **relevant part of the error stack** is this

```
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 122, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 349, in serialize
    self.serialize_queryset(queryset)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 321, in serialize_queryset
    self.handle_reverse_field(obj, field, field_name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 243, in handle_reverse_field
    values = [reverse_value(related) for related in getattr(obj, field_name).iterator()]
```

Looking at the stack, looks like there's a problem resolving the **reverse reference** of `ROI` to `Series`. `Series` has a `roi` field pointing to `ROI`, and I think the serializer thinks the `roi` field belongs to `ROI` class (incorrect) instead of to `Series` (correct). The expression *infinite loop* comes to my mind.

Besides, **if I delete the `roi` field from `Series` model class, it works**

I'm not sure about if it's a bug of django-geojson plugin (using the last version) or something wrong with my code (most likely). I've tried with the default json serializer, and still getting the same error. And also tried to inherit all model classes from gismodels instead of models. No effect.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it. Looks like [there is a bug in the django-geojson plugin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson/issues/23). It can't handle the backward relations. So, I just told Django to [**avoid the backward relation creation** between `ROI` and `Series`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

```
class Series(gismodels.Model):
    # Prevents django to create a backwards relation between ROI and Series
    roi = models.ForeignKey(ROI, related_name='+')
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator)
```